# Jquery countdown plugin doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I need your help.

I'm trying to set a jquery countdown to my website, but i don't know why, it doesn't work! i can't see anything: i've insert the html div, and set the links for jquery codes, css, etc. 
[this](https://thimble.webmaker.org/en-US/project/16981/edit) 
is my editing page.

and this is the complete code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Awesome Webpage created on Fri, 27 Sep 2013 09:24:37 GMT</title>
     <link href="http://corso-chitarrastudio.com/county.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://corso-chitarrastudio.com/county.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://corso-chitarrastudio.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://corso-chitarrastudio.com/county.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#my-count-down').county({ endDateTime: new Date('2013/10/12 21:28:00'), reflection: false, animation: 'scroll', theme: 'black' });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        background: url(http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/9963351894_c763ec6368_o.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position:center center !important;
    background-attachment:fixed !important;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto !important;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto !important;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto !important;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto !important;
      }

      h1 {  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
           font-size:42px;
           color: #c3c1c1; 
           width: 340px;
           text-transform:none;
           text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
           margin: -40px auto 35px auto;
           text-align: center;
           letter-spacing: -2px;
        line-height: 0.87;}

      #testo {

        width: 876px;
        margin: 20px auto 10px auto;}

      #contatore2 {
        width: 350px !important;
        margin: 20px auto auto auto;
        overflow: visible;
        padding-left: 20px;}

      #titolo2 {

        width: 532px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center ;
      }
    </style>
       </head>
  <body>
    <div id='testo'>
      <img src='http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3696/9966911376_585f718fc0_o.png'></div>

     <div id="my-count-down">
    </div>
       <div id='titolo2'><img id='titolo2' src='http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5516/9966872034_cc1eecbca5_o.png'></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Is your browser throwing any error?

Comment: Mozilla thimble is blocking loading files like jquery. I Copied your code to jsfiddle and it looks like is working. ok. http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/5sdXB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine, it must be something in your setup somewhere else causing the problem

As a general tip, your script files should go as close to the bottom of the document as possible, generally just before the closing body tag, both script files and inline scripts.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle with all your own code: http://jsfiddle.net/danwellman/EAjhb/